# Prventing .DS_Store from being created in my web projects

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard

How can I prevent OSX .DS_Store files from being created in my PHP projects? It's so annoying and I have to manually delete them when I want to put my app online or compress it and send it.

Thanks.

Comment: As a side note: If you're pushing your code to git you can add it to your gitignore file. Just thought i'd mention that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer: you can't. But, why do you care? They don't hurt if you deploy them to the web server. Also you can make a script to delete them, especially if you make a script to zip/tar your distribution you can also let it either delete the files or tar/zip in a way ignoring them. Like `tar cfX dist.tar ./.DS_Store *` will tar all folders/files in the current directory but exclude (capital X switch) the .DS_Store file.

Comment: As a perfectionist I actually do care :) + it may confuse Windows users. Do you have the command to recursively delete them from a directory?

Comment: find . -name ".DS_Store" -exec rm -f {} \; (note the backslash in front of the semicolon"

Comment: they can also cause issues with web deploy